# Duplicate/nested nodes on d3 for any new data updating force directive graph

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, d3-force-directed

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-wtjc86?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fzoomable.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

When new data hits my d3 service it loads the new data set but the old isn't removed. Therefore I have duplicate nodes inside its parent node 'g' element. New to d3, however I've done lots of reading around `selection.join()` instead of `enter().append()`. I've also read up on ways to add `node.exit().remove();` and `node.merge(node);` at specific points.

As you can see from the dom, all new node properties are in the `<g class="node">` element, duplicated, not replacing the original data. Therefore I get a overlapping of content.

[image]

Here is the way my nodes are built...

```
const zoomContainer = d3.select('svg g');

const node = zoomContainer.selectAll('g').data(nodes, function (d) {
  return d.id;
});

//zoomContainer.selectAll('.node').data(node).exit().remove();

const nodeEnter = node
  .join('g')
  .attr('class', 'node')
  .call(
    d3
      .drag()
      .on('start', (d) => this.dragended(d3, d, simulation))
      .on('drag', function dragged(d) {
        d.fx = d3.event.x;
        d.fy = d3.event.y;
      })
      .on('end', (d) => this.dragended(d3, d, simulation))
  );

nodeEnter
  .append('circle')
  .style('fill', '#fff')
  .style('cursor', 'pointer')
  .style('fill-opacity', '1')
  .style('stroke-opacity', '0.5')
  .attr('id', (d, i) => d.id)
  .attr('r', 28);

nodeEnter
  .append('image')
  .attr('xlink:href', 'https://github.com/favicon.ico')
  .attr('x', -15)
  .attr('y', -60)
  .attr('width', 16)
  .attr('class', 'image')
  .style('cursor', 'pointer')
  .attr('height', 16);

const nodeText = nodeEnter
  .data(nodes)
  .append('text')
  .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .style('cursor', 'pointer')
  .attr('dy', -3)
  .attr('y', -25)
  .attr('class', 'nodeText')
  .attr('id', 'nodeText');

nodeText
  .selectAll('tspan')
  .data((d, i) => d.label)
  .join('tspan')
  .attr('class', 'nodeTextTspan')
  .text((d) => d)
  .style('font-size', '12px')
  .attr('x', -10)
  .attr('dx', 10)
  .attr('dy', 15);
```

I probably could clear the graph by force but I like and need the way `.join()` can compare what's changed and the options to use `enter().append().exit()`. If anybody can see why duplicates are not being removed/merged I would appreciate it.

UPDATE:

If I use `enter().append('g')` instead of `join('g')` I then get a better result. I can use `zoomContainer.selectAll('.node').data(node).exit().remove();` before hand and my nodes do get updated but only after clicking update twice. If I use `join('g')` they duplicate and I am unable to use `zoomContainer.selectAll('.node').data(node).exit().remove();`

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-wtjc86?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fzoomable.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I've changed the code in the demo... they are no longer duplicating, but new items are nesting within the 'g' element.

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `.selectAll('.node')` for selecting a class.

Comment: ok so, yer, I've been playing with .node and node. With .node I get duplicates inside the g and just node I get duplicates outside

Comment: Ive added an image to demo the duplication inside the <g>. If I .selectAll('node') the old <g> nodes remain along with the new

Comment: The _exit arrays seem to be empty. Although they correctly represent how many nodes exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Targeting the `<g>` element rather than the class and then using `exit().remove()` seemed to have done the trick... I was adding a class attribute at the `.enter()` level in `.join()` and then doing the exit on that. [Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-ngqqqk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fzoomable.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
const node = zoomContainer
  .selectAll('.node')
  .data(this.nodes, function (d) {
    return d.id;
  });
zoomContainer.selectAll('g').data(node).exit().remove();
```